# CodeIgniter Default Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I am tring to create default controller for no matter what URL you access to.
Meaning, custom 404.

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions
{
var $ci;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::CI_Exceptions();
    $this->ci =& get_instance();
}

function show_404($page = '')
{
  //load view here

}
```

}

I am getting get_instance is undefined. (because it was defined after the libraries get called)
Is there a way to create custom 404 controller in codeignigter 1.7.2 without playing with the system core code.

Thanks

Comment: "Because it was defined after the libraries get called" does not make sense.  If it was defined /after/ it should be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://maestric.com/doc/php/codeigniter_404

i have used this solution and it works for me in CI 1.7

Answer (score 2):

[Upgrade to CodeIgniter 2.0](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/05/upgrading-to-codeigniter-2.0) because [its stable](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/10/codeigniter-2.0-is-stable) and use:

```
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to customize the 404 page, you can do so under the `/system/application/errors/error_404.php` page. The one caveat with this is that you can't use the `$this` object, it's strictly HTML/CSS or built-in PHP (no access to your libraries, models, etc.).

This is the page that CodeIgniter will display by default when it can't find a controller to handle a request.

Not sure if that's why you're trying to do or not, but that would be the simplest way to create a custom 404 page.

Comment: +1 assuming this is what OP wants, why bother reinventing the wheel

Comment: Thanks, I need A Controller and not HTML.

Comment: You could always put `redirect('controller/function')` into the `errors/error_404.php` page.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine.  Make sure it's in the 'application/libraries' folder, and make sure your config has 'MY_' set as the custom library name.

Also, if you are doing `function __construct(){}`, you can do `parent::__construct()`.

Comment: I did what you explained, this is not working...
Any other way to create Custom  CONTROLLER(!) for 404? Thanks